# Fixing dropped frames in 3 different video resolution files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am looking for a way to automatically examine 3 video files of the same content, but using 3 different resolutions (320x180, 640x360, 1280x720), and identify dropped frames and replace effected frames from keyframe to keyframe with audio, ensuring the audio waveform lines up with the other files.

In essence, each file would have exactly the same number of frames and each audio wave file would line up exactly in each separate file.

Is this possible using ffmpeg?

Comment: Hi William and welcome to Superuser. That's seems like quite a task! What steps have you tried yourself? What did your research show as feasible solutions?

Comment: Dropped frames can be replaced with duplication but missing/distorted audio can only be replaced with silence. Also, frames dropped during ffmpeg transcoding don't affect audio timing. How were these files generated?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to FFMPEG... But the research I have been doing suggests that it certainly might be possible.

**Identifying dropped frames:**

## !/bin/bash

rm framediffs.lis

ffmpeg -i MPEG0004.AVI f%d.png

framenum=1
while [ $framenum -lt 50 ]
do
file1=f$(( $framenum )).png
file2=f$(( $framenum + 1 )).png
compare -metric RMSE $file1 $file2 NULL: 2>diff.lis
fdiff=`cat diff.lis |cut -d ' ' -f 1`
echo $file1 $file2 $fdiff>>framediffs.lis
framenum=$(( $framenum + 1 ))
done

cat framediffs.lis

## Simulate some dropped frames:

compare -metric RMSE f45.png f47.png NULL:
compare -metric RMSE f45.png f48.png NULL:
compare -metric RMSE f46.png f48.png NULL:
compare -metric RMSE f47.png f50.png NULL:

then if need be, cut bad portion of file...

**Cutting a segmant without re-encoding:**
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 -c copy cut_video.mp4

Or replace a segment from file that doesnt show loss...

**Replacing segment from a good file:**
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf trim=X -c:a copy out.mp4
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf trim=X,setpts='if(eq(N,0),0,PTS)' -c:a copy out.mkv

If its an audio dicrepency, extract audio and then remux bad file...

**Extracting audio from file and remuxing (I think selecting a segment between 2 keyframes should be possible):**
ffmpeg -i vid.mkv -map 0:2 -ac 2 aud.wav
avconv -i INPUT_FILE_WITH_BROKEN_SOUND.mp4 -i SECOND_INPUT_FILE.mkv -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:1 OUTPUT.mp4

As I said, I am a newbie and would appreciate thoughts to avoid time wasters.
Thanks!